# Compute ecies hkdf symetric key with pycryptodome

Tags: python, cryptography, google-pay, pycryptodome, hkdf

Context: i'm working on making a python version of [paymentmethodtoken](https://github.com/google/tink/tree/master/apps/paymentmethodtoken/src/main/java/com/google/crypto/tink/apps/paymentmethodtoken) from the [google tink](https://github.com/google/tink) library to work with gpay messages. For that i use only python and PyCryptodome.

With that said i'm currently trying to implement an equivalent of the [kem function](https://github.com/google/tink/blob/9753ffddd4d04aa56e0605ff4a0db46f2fb80529/apps/paymentmethodtoken/src/main/java/com/google/crypto/tink/apps/paymentmethodtoken/PaymentMethodTokenHybridDecrypt.java#L83):

```java
private byte[] kem(JsonObject json, final byte[] contextInfo) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    int demKeySize = protocolVersionConfig.aesCtrKeySize + protocolVersionConfig.hmacSha256KeySize;
    byte[] ephemeralPublicKey =
        Base64.decode(
            json.get(PaymentMethodTokenConstants.JSON_EPHEMERAL_PUBLIC_KEY).getAsString());
    byte[] sharedSecret = recipientKem.computeSharedSecret(ephemeralPublicKey);
    return Hkdf.computeEciesHkdfSymmetricKey(
        ephemeralPublicKey,
        sharedSecret,
        PaymentMethodTokenConstants.HMAC_SHA256_ALGO,
        PaymentMethodTokenConstants.HKDF_EMPTY_SALT,
        contextInfo,
        demKeySize);
  }
```

the equivalent in python:

```py
    def __kem(self, signed_message: SignedMessage, context_info: bytearray) -> bytearray:
        dem_key_size: int = 64
        ephemeral_public_key: bytes = base64.b64decode(signed_message.ephemeral_public_key)
        shared_secret: bytearray = self.__compute_shared_secret(bytearray(ephemeral_public_key))
        empty_salt: bytearray = bytearray()
        # to do
        return self.__compute_ecies_hkdf_symmetric_key(ephemeral_public_key, shared_secret, empty_salt, context_info, dem_key_size)
```

```py
    def __compute_ecies_hkdf_symmetric_key(self, ephemeral_public_key: bytes, shared_secret: bytearray,
                                           salt: bytearray, context_info: bytearray, dem_key_size: int) -> bytearray:
        # TODO: add function body
        hkdf_input: bytes = ephemeral_public_key + shared_secret
        key1, key2 = HKDF(master=bytes("something goes here", "utf-8"), hashmod=SHA256, salt=salt, key_len=dem_key_size)

        pass
```

From what i can see google tink [computeEciesHkdfSymmetricKey](https://google.github.io/tink/javadoc/tink/1.1.0/com/google/crypto/tink/subtle/Hkdf.html) ([code](https://github.com/google/tink/blob/9753ffddd4d04aa56e0605ff4a0db46f2fb80529/java_src/src/main/java/com/google/crypto/tink/subtle/Hkdf.java#L47)) don't work at all like [PyCryptodome HKDF](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/protocol/kdf.html#hkdf).
my question is, does a equivalent of computeEciesHkdfSymmetricKey exist in pycryptomde or another librarie and if not, is it possible to reproduce the same behaviour ?

Comment: _From what i can see google tink computeEciesHkdfSymmetricKey don't work att all like PyCryptodome HKDF._ Really? I would assume just the opposite. `computeEciesHkdfSymmetricKey()` seems to essentially call the Tink method `Hkdf.computeHkdf()` (except for concatenating the first two parameters to the input keying material), which implements HKDF according to RFC5869, which is what the Python method `Crypto.Protocol.KDF.HKDF()` also does according to the description.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Topaco, you are right i just missread the javadoc i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i did:

```py
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import HKDF

def __compute_ecies_hkdf_symmetric_key(self, ephemeral_public_key: bytes, shared_secret: bytearray, salt: bytearray, context_info: bytearray, dem_key_size: int) -> bytearray:
    hkdf_input: bytes = ephemeral_public_key + shared_secret
    keys = HKDF(master=hkdf_input, hashmod=SHA256, salt=salt, key_len=dem_key_size, context=context_info)
    if isinstance(keys, bytes):
        return bytearray(keys)
    elif isinstance(keys, tuple(bytes)):
        return bytearray(keys[0])
    else:
        raise GooglePaymentDecryptMessageError("type of hkdf is not compatible")
```